# Can't get mongoose to slow down updates to prevent out of memory

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, async.js

I need to do a massive upload to my database. I have an array with id's and for each id some code builds the complete array that has to be send to the database. If I just use a for loop and send it all i get an `FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - process out of memory`. So I started looking at ways to solve this. It seems I should update my database using async.js. I quite liked the idea of async.eachLimit thinking it can send 10 updates, wait for the 10 callbacks, then send the next 10 etc.

I hope this is indeed the way async.eachLimit will work but I can't get it to work:

```
function convert() {
    console.log('Converting...');
    var ids = Object.keys(jsonHourly);

    async.eachLimit(ids, 10, function(id, callback){
        console.log('New Subset for ' + id);

        var measurements = someCalculation(id)

        itemCollectionDB.update({'_id': id}, { $set : { graphData : measurements } }, {multi: true}, function(err, numAffected){
            if (err){
                console.log(err)
            }
            console.log('callback for ' + id);
            callback();
        });
    }, function(err){
        if (err){
            console.log(err)
        }
        console.log('A set of 10 has been saved')
    });

    console.log('Done but give the database some time to process it all!')
}
```

This however outputs:

```
Converting...
New Subset for 24
New Subset for 68
New Subset for 69
New Subset for 70
New Subset for 71
New Subset for 72
New Subset for 73
New Subset for 74
New Subset for 75
New Subset for 76
Done but give the database some time to process it all!
callback for 24
New Subset for 77
callback for 69
New Subset for 78
callback for 68
New Subset for 79
callback for 73
New Subset for 80
callback for 70
New Subset for 81
callback for 75
New Subset for 82
callback for 76
New Subset for 83
callback for 72
New Subset for 84
```

With the last 2 lines repeating for all id's. What is going on here? I would think I'd get 10 callbacks, then the next 10 subsets are send.

(id's contain roughly 24000 id's, I'm planning to increase the step size later when this works to make it go a bit faster)

Comment: Which version of `node` is being used?

Comment: `async.eachLimit` doesn't do its work in batches of 10 like your thinking. It enforces a limit of 10 outstanding async updates at a time (which is more efficient). The final callback won't be called until _all_ of the updates have completed.

Comment: @ JohnnyHK So when "New Subset for 77" is printed it will have removed all stuff from Subset 24? My code is actually running correctly then right? It would always limit the strain to 10 calls at a time?

Comment: @SecondLemon Yes, your code appears to be working just fine.

Comment: have you considered using bulk operations? https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk/ and http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Collection.html#initializeUnorderedBulkOp